# How do I prevent Windows 10 from disconnecting mapped drives?

Tags: windows-10, samba, mapped-drive

I have a mapped drive on Windows 10 Enterprise that keeps disconnecting itself, sometimes even when I'm in the middle of doing things using files on that share.  I have a desktop shortcut to it; if I click that after the drive has disconnected, I get this error message:

[image: System dialog titled Problem with Shortcut, saying: 'The item that this shortcut refers to has been changed or moved, so this shortcut will no longer work properly. Do you want to delete this shortcut? Yes/No']

What's actually happening is that when I click the shortcut, the system re-maps the drive immediately, but not before displaying the error message.  If I keep a "This PC" window open, I can see the drive appear in the list a moment later.  So if I click "No", then the shortcut will work until Windows decides to disconnect the drive again, after which I'll have to go through the same stupid error message again.

When I created this mapped drive, I checked the "Reconnect at sign-in" box.  It doesn't seem to have helped.

I have tried issuing the command `net config server /autodisconnect:-1` to turn off automatic disconnecting; it had no effect.

I've tried deleting the mapping and recreating it with `net use Z: \\sharename\path /user:SHIRE\baggins /persistent:yes`, but the problem continues.

This is super-annoying, not just because of the "Problem with Shortcut" dialog, but because it keeps disrupting my work flow.  Any open file explorer windows showing the mapped drive's contents get closed.  If I have a file open in Notepad++, it will inform me that the file I'm editing no longer exists, and ask what to do with the copy in memory (keep/discard).

In case it's relevant, this particular share lives on a Linux server running Samba.  I can post the config file for that if needed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have exactly the same issue. In my case, the share is on a USB hard drive connected to my Linksys router. Yup, that's Samba using SMB 1.0.

Comment: Nope, never found a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Using: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch11.html

Try adjusting:

- change notify timeout
- deadtime

Comment: deadtime is set to zero, so there's no timeout.  The notify timeout is for alerting clients to changed files in a folder, I think.  I'm not sure its relevant.  Thanks, though.